# Segmentation Fault with fread() from my created binary file

Tags: c

I'm new to c from python. I'm trying to write two c scripts, one that reads a plain-text file in FASTA format (for DNA/RNA/protein sequences). They look like this...

```
>sequence1
ATCTATGTCGCTCGCTCGAGAGCTA
>sequence2
CGTCGCTGGGATCGATTTCGATAGCT
>sequence3
AAATATAACTCGCTAGCTCGATCGATC
>sequence4
CTCTCTCCTCTCTCTATATAGGGG
```

...where individual sequences are separated by ">" characters. Within each sequence, the actual sequence and its label are separated by a newline character. (ie ">label \n sequence"). The script for reading the plain-text and then writing it to a binary file seems to work. However, when I try to read the binary file and print its contents, I get a Segmentation Fault (Core dump).

I tried to produce a reduced example for posting here, but that example seems to work without error. So, I feel forced to attach my whole code snippets here. I must be missing something.

Here's the first script which reads in a plain text fasta file, splits it first by the ">" character, and then by the newline character, to make "sequence" structures for each sequence in the above FASTA file. These structures are then written to "your_sequences.bin".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024
struct sequence {
    char *sequence;
    char *label;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    FILE *fptr;
    char buffer[BUZZ_SIZE];
    char fasta[BUZZ_SIZE];
    char *token;
    char *seqs[3];
    int idx = 0;
    const char fasta_delim[2] = ">";
    const char newline[3] = "\n";

    /* Read-in plain-text */
    fptr = fopen(argv[1],"r");

     while (fgets(buffer, BUZZ_SIZE, fptr) != NULL) {
         strcat(fasta, buffer);
     }

     fclose(fptr);

     /* Process text, first by splitting by > and then by \n for each sequence, and then write to binary */

     FILE *out;
     out = fopen("your_sequences.bin","wb");
     struct sequence final_entry;

     token = strtok(fasta,fasta_delim);
     while (token != NULL) {
         seqs[idx++] = token; 
         token = strtok(NULL,fasta_delim);
        }

     for (idx=0; idx<4; idx++) {
        token = strtok(seqs[idx],newline);
        char *this_seq[1];
        int p = 0;
        while (token != NULL) {
            this_seq[p] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL,newline);
            p++;
        }
        final_entry.label = this_seq[0];
        final_entry.sequence = this_seq[1];
        printf("%s\n%s\n\n", final_entry.label, final_entry.sequence);
        fwrite(&final_entry, sizeof(struct sequence), 1, out);
     }
     fclose(out);

     return(0);
}
```

This outputs, as expected from the fprint() statement toward the bottom:

```
sequence1
ATCTATGTCGCTCGCTCGAGAGCTA

sequence2
CGTCGCTGGGATCGATTTCGATAGCT

sequence3
AAATATAACTCGCTAGCTCGATCGATC

sequence4
CTCTCTCCTCTCTCTATATAGGGG
```

I'm thinking the error has to be somewhere in the above script (ie my binary file is messed up), because the Segmentation Fault is caused by the fread() statement in the script below. I don't think I've made an error in calling fread(), but maybe I'm wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUZZ_SIZE 1024

struct sequence {
    char *sequence;
    char *label; };

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    struct sequence this_seq;
    int n;
    FILE *fasta_bin;

    fasta_bin = fopen(argv[1],"rb");
    for (n=0;n<4;n++) {
        fread(&this_seq, sizeof(struct sequence), 1, fasta_bin);
        printf (">%s\n%s\n", this_seq.label, this_seq.sequence);
    }

    fclose(fasta_bin);

    return(0);
```

}

This outputs the segmentation fault

```
[1]    8801 segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've tinkered around with and gone over this a good amount over the past couple hours. I hope I haven't made some stupid mistake a wasted your time!

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Terminology: C programs are not called "scripts", just as C itself is not accounted among the scripting languages.

Comment: ` fread(&this_seq, sizeof(struct sequence), 1, fasta_bin);` has not sense in C, nothing good can be awaited while reading pointers from file (and write is wrong too, but not gives error). Must use different code

Comment: `fwrite(&final_entry, sizeof(struct sequence), 1, out);` -- this is where your problem is (and the corresponding `fread` too). You cannot just write pointers to a file and read they back again. You need to serialize your data appropriately.

Comment: After reading the answers below, also know that every function in the C-library that takes a string (`char *`) as a parameter requires that the sequence be *nul-terminated* (so it knows when to stop reading), otherwise you fly off the end reading through memory you do not own until you just happen to stumble upon a *nul-character* (e.g. `'\0'` -- which is just decimal `0`) or SegFault.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Got it, thanks for the information! So "c program" would be the correct designation?

Comment: @JacekCz (and @Ajay) Ahh, that's what I get for following random online tutorials! Thanks for the help, your comments along with some great answers below have me feeling a lot more in touch with this important distinction...and the nature of pointers

Comment: @kamses, "C program" is fine.  Or if you want to emphasize that you're talking about the source code, "'C source" or "C source code" works.  (The fact that there is a big difference between the source code and the corresponding executable is one of the main reasons why the term "script" does not apply.)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Understood. One question though, is the null terminator never implicitly added by c when reading through character arrays? So for instance... `char *string = "a string";` is better stated char  `*string = "a string\0";` and c will never add `\0` on its own?

Comment: C always provides nul-terminating characters when **initializing** an array or pointer from a *string literal*. So any time you see `char *s = "string";` (creating `s` as a *pointer-to-char* (*pointer-to-string-literal* in readonly memory)) or `char s[] = "string";` (creating an *array-of-chars*), both will be nul-terminated strings. Aside from initialization, it is up to **you** to insure (1) sufficient space for termination; and (2) that the last character is in fact `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting segmentation fault because in your program you are using pointer without allocating memory to them:

```
        printf (">%s\n%s\n", this_seq.label, this_seq.sequence);
```

You first need to allocate memory to `this_seq.label` and `this_seq.sequence` pointers, something like this:

```
this_seq.sequence = malloc(size_of_sequence);
if (this_seq.sequence == NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

this_seq.label = malloc(size_of_label);
if (this_seq.label == NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

and then read the data into them, like this:

```
fread(this_seq.sequence, size_of_sequence, 1, fasta_bin);
fread(this_seq.label, size_of_label, 1, fasta_bin);
```

Comment: almost hit, but Your receipt is wrong. While reading struct, internal pointers will be lost to random value

Comment: @H.S. Thank you! This worked! Thank you for looking over my code and helping me clarify my understanding of pointers, where the actual data is, and memory allocation. I had another question about malloc though. In practice the labels and sequences can be of variable length, as noted by JohnBollinger in an answer. So say I shoot high and allocated and pass as arg2 to fread() something like 1024 bytes for each. How does c know to stop at the next sequence versus reading part of the next into the present structure? Is this because of `\0` ?

Comment: @kamses `fread()` stops when it either read the total number of objects or EOF reached/error occurred. It does not stop at `\0`. Check [**this**](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=87152233), might help. I would suggest you read about [**File I/O**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) in C language.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking the error has to be somewhere in the above script (ie my
>   binary file is messed up),

Sort of.

> because the Segmentation Fault is caused by
>   the fread() statement in the script below.

I'm fairly confident that the error occurs not in the `fread()` but in the following `printf()`.

> I don't think I've made an
>   error in calling fread(), but maybe I'm wrong.

Your `fread()` corresponds to the `fwrite()`.  There is every reason to expect that you will accurately read back what was written.  The main problem here is a common one for C neophytes: you've misunderstood the nature of C strings (a null-terminated *array* of `char`), and failed to appreciate the crucial, but subtle, distinction between arrays and pointers.

To expand on that a bit, C does not have a first-class string data type.  Instead, the standard library provides "string" functions that operate on sequences of objects of type `char`, where the end of the sequence is marked by a terminator `char` with the value 0.  Such sequences typically are contained in `char` arrays, and *always* can be treated as if they were. Because that's what the standard library supports, that convention is ubiquitously used in programs and third-party libraries, too.

C, however, has no mechanism for passing arrays to functions or receiving them as return values.  Nor do the assignment operator or most others work on arrays -- not even the indexing operator, `[]`.  Instead, in most contexts, values of array type are automatically converted to pointers to the first array element, and these can be passed around and used as operands to a wide variety of operators.  Seeing (part of) this, inexperienced C programmers often mistakenly identify strings with such pointers instead of with the pointed-to data.

Of course a pointer value is just an address.  You can copy it around and store it at any number of locations in the program, but this does nothing to the pointed-to data.  And now I finally come around to the point: you can also write out a pointer value and read it back in, *as your programs do*, but it is rarely useful to do so, because the pointed-to data don't come along when you do that.  Unless you read the pointer back into the same process that wrote it, the read-back pointer value is unlikely to be valid, and it certainly does not have the same significance it did in the program that wrote it.

You must instead write the pointed-to data, but you have to choose a format.  In particular, titles and sequences generally have varying lengths, and one of the key things you need to decide is how, if at all, your binary format should reflect that.  If I might be so bold, however, I have a suggestion for a well-defined format you could use: Fasta format!  Seriously.

There's not much you can do short of data compression to express fasta-format data more compactly, as that format does little more than it needs to do to express the varying-length data it conveys.  The question you need to answer, then, is what exactly you're trying to achieve by your reformatting -- both the reason for reformatting at all, and based on that, what your target format actually is.

Comment: That's a good explanation to impart the "Am I a string?" or "Am I a character array?" thought process in a new programmer (though it is kinda scary with all the things that don't work with arrays `:)`

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation of why my diagnosis was "sort of" right. This all makes a lot more sense now - pointers and what is being pointed to. It's a bit perplexing, and it doesn't help that I think a lot of free online tutorials are using slightly erroneous code. Coming from python it is going to take a little getting used to the need to allocate specific amounts of memory when working with variably sized data elements. In truth, I don't have any pressing need to store fasta formatted files in binary. This is a self-imposed example geared toward learning to do things in c.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `struct sequence` doesn't actually carry any salvageable information, it only contains pointers.

Pointers carry memory addresses, they point where the actual information is in memory, but of course if you are reading the file in another process with an entirely different memory space, the information won't be there. In fact, you are likely to crash for trying to interact with memory space that wasn't properly initialized first.

A very simple solution is, don't use pointers, use arrays:

```
struct sequence
{
    char sequence[1024];
    char label[1024];
}
```

Now the structure actually carry the data, no longer just pointers. You will be able to read and write it to file with no worries. However, some code will need to be changed further.

You can no longer assign data to them like `x.label = label`, you need to use `strcpy()`, like `strcpy(x.label, label)`. Those changes will need to be made everywhere in the code where you assign values to the properties of this structure.

Comment: It is worth noting that your proposed solution, which is indeed nice and simple, places an arbitrary limit on the length of the sequences (and titles) that can be conveyed, and changing that limit will produce incompatible files.  Additionally, this approach will tend to produce outputs larger than the inputs -- *much* larger in the case of the OP's example.  But those characteristics may be perfectly acceptable for the OP's undisclosed purposes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well that limit was already imposed, he is reading data with 1024 byte buffers and trusting they are complete. But, judging from the example, pretty sure this limit is more than sufficient and could be even smaller.

Comment: @Havenard Thanks! This should also fix my problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Even though this does put a limit on the size of labels/sequences, wouldn't another limit be imposed by by calling malloc(byte-size) later on? Or is there a way to keep that open-ended?

Comment: @kamses It can have dynamic length, but it will require a substantial amount of code. If you wish to keep your code straight to the point, I suggest you switch to C++. It offers easy ways of doing that. In C 90% of what you do is manage memory, and as consequence the code can look so dirty it's hard to find the actual program in the middle of the sea of mallocs, buffers and pointers. C is fast, but it's not pretty.

Comment: @kamses, yes, you can keep it open-ended -- after all, Python's C implementation does.  To do so, you keep track of how much you have allocated, and when you fill that up you allocate a larger space or an additional space and go on.  Obviously, I'm putting that in very general terms.  In that case, your format must also have a mechanism for communicating either the sizes or the boundaries of the parts.  Fasta format does that with delimiters.